# AngularJS + PhoneGap Camera - How can I get $scope on success

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I don't know why but the $scope is not working on callback of camera. (OnSuccess function)

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="capturePhoto();">Capture</button>
<span>{{ test }}</span>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.capturePhoto = function(){

        $scope.test = "test 1";

        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });

    }

    function onSuccess(imageData) {

        var image = imageData;

        alert($scope); // [object Object]
        alert($scope.test); // test1
        $scope.test = "test 2"; // Problem: do not show on screen
        alert($scope.test); // test2

    }

});
```

The page is still showing test1. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you get out of angular digest cycle with the plugin callback, angular just never know that there is change, and can't update.

The simplest way is to use $apply :

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {

    $scope.$apply(function (){
        var image = imageData;

        alert($scope); // [object Object]
        alert($scope.test); // test1
        $scope.test = "test 2"; // Problem: do not show on screen
        alert($scope.test); // test2
    });

}
```

In my opinion the best way is to use promise :

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $q) {

$scope.capturePhoto = function(){

    $scope.test = "test 1";
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.promise.then(function (imageData){
         var image = imageData;

        alert($scope); // [object Object]
        alert($scope.test); // test1
        $scope.test = "test 2"; // Problem: do not show on screen
        alert($scope.test); // test2
    }, function (error){});

    navigator.camera.getPicture(defer.resolve, defer.reject, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });

}
```

Comment: I've just tried the first option and worked as a charm. I'll try the second option later.